# Unsetting nested descendants of a particular ancestor based on an key and if empty unset the ancestor as well

Tags: php

Let's imagine we have this multidimensional array which contains nested arrays

```
$arr = [
    1 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'families' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 3
            ],
        ]
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'families' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2,
                'products' => [
                    1 => 'John Doe'
                ],
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 3,
                'products' => [],
            ],
        ]
    ],
    3 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'products' => [
            1 => 'Hi',
            2 => 'Hello',
        ]
    ],
    4 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'families' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 3
            ],
        ]
    ],
];
```

I need to keep all ancestors and descendants where there is at least one item in the key "products", all other arrays should be unset.

So, in this particular example, the result should be as follows:

```
$arr = [
    2 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'families' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2,
                'products' => [
                    1 => 'John Doe'
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ],
    3 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'products' => [
            1 => 'Hi',
            2 => 'Hello',
        ]
    ],
];
```

Basically, what needs to be done is to go from the most inner array up and asking:

1) Is our key "products" empty? Yes

2) Is our key "families" either empty or not set? Yes

3) unset this array

Comment: You need multiple nested `foreach()` loops which utilize `$k=>$v` which will allow you to unset the appropriate ancestor. You should make an attempt...

Comment: You don't need a multinested one. That would add so much overheard @MonkeyZeus. Plus you will never know how many levels there are so you would have to use recursion. Much easier to loop through the base then json_encode each child and search the string for "products" like in my answer lol.

Comment: Your solution fails to produce the output requested by OP, fyi...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you're right, it does fail. I've tried multiple solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: @Jiri Yes, please reference my first comment for future use.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    1 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'families' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 3
            ],
        ]
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'families' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2,
                'products' => [
                    1 => 'John Doe'
                ],
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 3,
                'products' => [],
            ],
        ]
    ],
    3 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'products' => [
            1 => 'Hi',
            2 => 'Hello',
        ]
    ],
    4 => [
        'id' => 1,
        'families' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 2
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 3
            ],
        ]
    ],
];

foreach($arr as $k => $a) {
    if(strpos(json_encode($a), "products") == 0){
        unset($arr[$k]);
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/tNSqs

Comment: Hey, 

thank you for the reply. This looks neat and although the issue is that it doesn't remove {"id":3,"products":[]}] ($arr[2]['families'][1])